# Colorir background da linha(row) no django admin

Tags: javascript, python, django

Tenho um codigo que esta funcionando, mas nao totalmente com o que quero, ele esta a colorir apenas a celula selecionada, quero colorir a linha inteira dependendo do status da coluna.. segue o codigo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#result_list tr td:nth-child(4)').each(function() {
if ($(this).text() == 'ARQUIVADO') {
  $(this).css({
      "background-color": 'yellow',
      "color" : "#000000"
  });
}
if ($(this).text() == 'TITULO EMITIDO') {
  $(this).css({
      "background-color": 'darkblue',
      "color" : "#FFFFFF"
  });
}
if ($(this).text() == 'PROCESSO LANÇADO') {
 $(this).css({
     "background-color": 'blue',
      "color" : "white"
  });
}
if ($(this).text() == 'TITULO ENTREGUE') {
  $(this).css({
      "background-color": 'green',
      "color" : "white"
  });
}

});
});
})(django.jQuery);
</script>
```

Como faz para colorir a linha inteira e nao so a celula ?

Comment: Também não pode alterar a pergunta acrescentando outra quando já possui respostas. No caso você teria que fazer outra pergunta, mas já coloquei no comentário lá uma solução.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode achar a linha que contém a palavra com `:contains` e aplicar a cor desejada na linha:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#result_list tr:contains("ARQUIVADO")').each(function() {
      $(this).css({
         "background-color": 'yellow',
       "color" : "#000000"
     });
   });
});
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#result_list tr:contains("ARQUIVADO")').each(function() {
      $(this).css({
         "background-color": 'yellow',
       "color" : "#000000"
     });
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="result_list">
   <tr>
      <td>
         1
      </td>
      <td>
         2
      </td>
      <td>
         3
      </td>
      <td>
         4
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         ARQUIVADO
      </td>
      <td>
         2
      </td>
      <td>
         3
      </td>
      <td>
         4
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         1
      </td>
      <td>
         2
      </td>
      <td>
         3
      </td>
      <td>
         ARQUIVADO
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Você pode usar para diferentes palavras:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var fundo, cor;
   $('#result_list tr').each(function() {
      if($(this).is(':contains("ARQUIVADO")')) fundo = 'yellow', cor = '#000';
      if($(this).is(':contains("RECEBIDO")')) fundo = 'red', cor = '#fff';
      if($(this).is(':contains("ENVIADO")')) fundo = 'blue', cor = '#fff';
      
      $(this).css({
         "background-color": fundo,
         "color" : cor
      });
      
      fundo = cor = '';
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="result_list">
   <tr>
      <td>
         1
      </td>
      <td>
         2
      </td>
      <td>
         3
      </td>
      <td>
         RECEBIDO
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         1
      </td>
      <td>
         2
      </td>
      <td>
         3
      </td>
      <td>
         ARQUIVADO
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         1
      </td>
      <td>
         2
      </td>
      <td>
         3
      </td>
      <td>
         ENVIADO
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         1
      </td>
      <td>
         2
      </td>
      <td>
         3
      </td>
      <td>
         NADA
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Repare que você está selecionando `$('#result_list tr td:nth-child(4)')` dessa forma, vai selecionar apenas o `td`. faça da seguinte forma `$('#result_list tr')` para conseguir aplicar o `css` na linhas invés de aplciar apenas ao `td` selecionado.

Comment: Desta forma ele coloriu todas as linhas na mesma cor, nao expliquei, mas ha outras funçoes, uma para cada status (arquivado, enviado, recebido, etc) e é necessario que seja uma cor diferente para cada linha, dependendo do status da coluna (no caso a coluna 4)

Comment: Nesse caso, tem que fazer uma seleção específica, por exemplo, se quer colorir a linha quatro, apenas faça isso `$('#result_list tr:nth-child(4)')`

Answer (score -1):

Onde coloco este código no Django-Admin?

(document).ready(function() {
var fundo, cor;
$('#result_list tr').each(function() {
if($(this).is(':contains("ARQUIVADO")')) fundo = 'yellow', cor = '#000';
if($(this).is(':contains("RECEBIDO")')) fundo = 'red', cor = '#fff';
if($(this).is(':contains("ENVIADO")')) fundo = 'blue', cor = '#fff';

```
  $(this).css({
     "background-color": fundo,
     "color" : cor
  });
  
  fundo = cor = '';
```

});
});